# Delete of Task in Lightning

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement where when a User click on Delete of a Task in Lightning Page then I want to redirect the user to Contact Record. Currently, its being redirected to List View of Contact.

Comment: @PirateX I  tried VF page as JS buttons are not allowed but its not working.

Comment: You're going to need a VF Page, and Controller..

Comment: @EricSSH No, redirection in Lightning does not work with VF page. There should be some different approach, I already trid with VF page and Controller.